# Javascript - Unable to read json key values - Unexpected token i in JSON at position 1 - sql query output problem

Tags: javascript, sql, json, array-agg

I'ved got this string generated from sql query (basically using ARRAY_AGG and some cases to format the output) that looks like this

```
{id:2,name_of_division:'super department1',attendance_radius:1000}
```

However, in javascript, I cant get any of the key values and its also causing JSON parse error.
I'ved tried validating this JSON and it looks perfectly fine.

Here are some of the troubleshooting, I have no idea what is causing it

```
console.log(clean_div_array_var[i].toString());
output ==> {id:2,name_of_division:'super department1',attendance_radius:1000}

console.log("id:" + clean_div_array_var[i].id);
output ==> id:undefined

console.log("name_of_division:" + clean_div_array_var[i].name_of_division);
output ==> name_of_division:undefined


JSON.parse(clean_div_array_var[i]);
output ==>
VM2561:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token i in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at get_all_key_of_div_array ((index):817)
    at render ((index):2321)
    at jquery.dataTables.min.js:18
    at Object.b.fnGetData (jquery.dataTables.min.js:12)
    at B (jquery.dataTables.min.js:17)
    at Ha (jquery.dataTables.min.js:25)
    at O (jquery.dataTables.min.js:16)
    at jquery.dataTables.min.js:49
    at i (jquery.dataTables.min.js:35)
```

I even try to stringify, then somehow remove quotes (I dont understand why this even appears) and then JSON parse. Same problem.

```
stringifyvar = JSON.stringify(clean_div_array_var[i])
output ==> "{id:2,name_of_division:'super department1',attendance_radius:1000}"

stringifyvar = stringifyvar.split('\"').join('');
console.log("stringify remove quote:" + stringifyvar);
output ==> stringify remove quote:{id:2,name_of_division:'super department1',attendance_radius:1000}

parsed_json_data = JSON.parse(stringifyvar);

output ==>
VM2503:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token i in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at get_all_key_of_div_array ((index):816)
    at render ((index):2320)
    at jquery.dataTables.min.js:18
    at Object.b.fnGetData (jquery.dataTables.min.js:12)
    at B (jquery.dataTables.min.js:17)
    at Ha (jquery.dataTables.min.js:25)
    at O (jquery.dataTables.min.js:16)
    at jquery.dataTables.min.js:49
    at i (jquery.dataTables.min.js:35)
```

How can I read any of the keys properly from this json

Comment: JSON requires object keys and strings to be in double quotes.

Comment: So that's not valid JSON. Don't try to create JSON by hand, always use a library function to ensure that everything is formatted correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result is not valid JSON. Valid format would be:

```
{"id":2, "name_of_division":"super department1", "attendance_radius":1000}
```

The keys have to be quoted, and the quotes around the string `super department1` have to be double quotes, not singlequotes.

You need to generate proper JSON if you want to be able to use `JSON.parse()` to process it.